# Метод split в python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Код:

```
a=input().split()
print(a)
```

При подаче на ввод строки `'1 2 3'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in <module>
        a=input().split()   File "<string>", line 1
    1 2 3
      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Выражение взято из примера, должно работать. В чем может быть загвоздка?

Comment: В Python 3  все нормально, во втором действительно такая проблема есть. Вы используете второй питон? Если да, укажите это в вопросе (и теге), дабы не возникало потом недопониманий.

Comment: Если пример из какой-то книжки, то лучше таки поставить третий питон вместо второго, а то в дальнейшем несоответствий будет ещё больше

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это не `split` - это `input` вываливает исключение. А все почему? Безблагодатность. [Документация](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) говорит вот что - `input` делает две вещи:

1) Читает из stdin.

2) Все, что прочитано, выполняется (`eval`).

Соответственно, строка `1 2 3` не может быть выполнена из-за неверного синтаксиса. В Py3 поведение `input()` изменили, чтобы люди больше не путались. Используйте [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). Или Python3. А еще можно воспользоваться библиотекой [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/), чтобы при внезапном переезде на другую версию ваш код не поломался, потому что в Py3 функция `raw_input()` отсутствует.

Answer (score 3):

Просто замени метод `input()` на `raw_input()`